# Django Rest Framework ListCreateAPIView not checking has_object_permissions?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've been trying to figure this out for almost a full day now, and I can't seem to figure out why `has_object_permission method` isn't called when the `ListCreateAPIView` is called in `DRF`. I've tried all the solutions I could find, but according to the docs `check_object_permissions` is called in this class already.

I know it has to be something stupid I'm missing. Code snippets are below, please help!

views.py:

```
from accountability.models import AccountabilityItem
from accountability.serializers import AccountabilityItemSerializer
from rest_framework import generics
from .permissions import InGroup

class AccountabilityItemListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = AccountabilityItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountabilityItemSerializer
    permission_classes = (InGroup,)
```

permissions.py:

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class InGroup(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
    """
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print('Checking for object')
        return False
```

Another note, I've added the `has_permission` method to the `permissions.py` file, and this method runs all the time no matter what.

Thanks!

Comment: "according to the docs check_object_permissions is called in this class" I don't think so, where did you read that ?

Comment: hmmm looking back at the docs now it seems that the generic DetailView is where I saw it, not ListView.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `has_object_permission` doesn't make sense for lists. It is intended for single instances.

What you want is to *filter* your list of objects so it only leaves those for which the user has some permissions. [DjangoObjectPermissionsFilter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangoobjectpermissionsfilter) does it but requires django-guardian. You might get a similar result but creating your own filtering class ([sources for DjangoObjectPermissionsFilter](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/filters.py#L279-L308))

Comment: Hmm alright. Let me ask you then, would using `DjangoObjectPermissionsfilter` make more sense then just defining the `get_queryset` method on this class?

Comment: I was also wondering this... From what I understand, you can use `get_queryset` to do a simple filtering of the objects displayed to the user (e.g. get just the items owned by the user making the request via `SELECT * FROM item WHERE item.owner = request.user`). If you use the `DjangoObjectPermissionsFilter`, you are also checking permissions at object level for each item returned to the user. So I would assume the latter method provides more security? Maybe @Linovia can help?